# JQuery after change img source bind is lost

Tags: jquery, image, bind, src

When I change image source bind event don't work anymore.

```
<img id='myImage' src='./images/myImage.png' />

 $(document).ready( function() {
     $("#myImage).bind("click", function(e) {
         //do something       
     });
 });

 function processFileUpload() {
     //...
     $("#myImage").attr("src", "images/" + fileName + ".png");
 }
```

After processFileUpload() is called when I click again myImage event click dont work anymore.
How it is possible to change image source without losing bind?

Comment: can I see your all code?

Comment: I can't post all the code and is a bit complex to extract only this part. But the problem is just that when I change image source the event don't work anymore.

Comment: I test my code. but your issue It didn't happen. so I think your code's side effect...

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the click event to the document, and give all of your img tags a class like `my-images`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.my-images', function(e){
        processFileUpload($(this));
    });

    function processFileUpload($img){
        $img.attr("src", "images/" + fileName + ".png");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't do this because I need to use IDs for multiple <img>. I would prefer to find an alternative way to update the image that do not impact on bind events.